# How do you format a text file after copy/pasting it from another text file?

Tags: python, format

I am using python and at the moment I can copy text from one text file to another. However I need to be able to take the text and and number each line of text. At this point I'm not sure how to insert more text after copying the text.

```
    with open("copyTo.txt", "w") as f1:
         for line in f:
             f1.write(line)
```

For example if I write:
"Hello everyone!
My name is Bob.
It's a nice day today."
I expect the outcome to look like this:

1. Hello everyone!
2. My name is Bob.
3. It's a nice day today.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it with `f-string` and `enumerate` like below.

```
with open("copyTo.txt", "w") as f1:
    for index,line in enumerate(f,start=1):
        f1.write(f'{index}. {line}')
```

Here you are enumerating the lines by assigning the start index to 1. Then using `f-string` you can format the string according to your wish and write to the output file.

Comment: `enumerate(f, 1)`, or it will start from 0

Comment: When I try to use this code it says that "f is not defined" and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: I assumed you already had file open

Comment: f = open('input.txt', 'r') you have to have it in the top and have to provide the file name from where you are reading lines.

Comment: If you already have a different file name for the input file you can pass it as first argument inside enumerate.

Comment: for extra bonus `f"{index:04}."` will lpad zeroes so that you don't get variable indentation and margins.